# Splitting 1600 line cs project in to multiple files- eg one per class. How to compile with csc?

Tags: c#, compilation, csc

I have a file called say project.cs which I now compile via csc project.cs into project.exe .

I now want to pull one of the classes- class1, used in this file out and house it in a separate file.

How would I go about this- what would the file need to be called/how would I compile my project from these two files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After splitting your file into multiple smaller files/classes, simply list them one by one after declaring the output type.

```
csc.exe /out:project.exe class1.cs class2.cs class3.cs
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this worked a treat. I need to mark this as answered or something don't I.. have forgotten how to do this.

Comment: You can click on the check mark next to this post :)

Comment: Lol... right infront of me ffs.. thanks again mate :)